# phpredis function mSet with ttl

Tags: php, redis, memcached, ttl, phpredis

I'm currently using memcached, but i'm trying move this mechanism to redis.

My goal is to save the entire array (key => value) every 1000 iterations.

Old solution:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
);
$memcached->setMulti($data, time()+864000);
```

New solution:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
);
$redis->mSet($data);
```

The operation of these scripts is almost identical.

As you can see, the redis can not set the expire date when I'm using multi (mSet function).

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MSET` doesn't support the `EX` and `PX` options available with `SET`. You have 2 options depending on your needs:

- If you need this to be atomic, use either [transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) or [Lua scripting](http://redis.io/commands/eval). An example with transactions (from `redis-cli`) would look like this:

  > MULTI

  OK

  > SET key1 value1 EX 10

  QUEUED

  > SET key2 value2 EX 10

  QUEUED

  > EXEC

I'm not familiar with phpredis, but it probably has an abstraction that handles this for you.

- If you don't need atomicity, you can just use [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) with multiple `SET` commands.